# Codigo PHP en JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

como les va? 
Tengo el siguiente conflicto, de antemano gracias por su ayuda

En una pagina php tengo un formulario tipo factura, en el puefo agregar lineas para agregar productos y de esa forma irlos sumando etc. esto lo tengo asi

```
<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="productCode2[]" id="productCode2_1" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="productName2[]" id="productName2_1" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>           
<td><input type="number" name="quantity2[]" id="quantity2_1" class="form-control quantity input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="price2[]" id="price2_1" class="form-control price input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="total2[]" id="total2_1" class="form-control total input-sm" autocomplete="off" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text" name="proveedor2[]" id="proveedor2_1" class="form-control price2 input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>
```

En la primera linea me funciona de maravilla, le agregue este codigo para que cargue los proveedores que tengo almacenados en una tabla de bases de datos por medio del siguiente codigo

```
    $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM app_proveedores Where user_code=".$_SESSION['user_code']." order by nombre asc";          
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<select class='form-control' id='proveedor2_1' name='proveedor2_1' >";
echo "<option value=''>Seleccione Proveedor</option>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value=" . $row['nombre'] . " >" . $row['nombre'] . "</option>";
    }
echo"</select>";
```

En la primera file me sirve de maravilla, me despliega todos los datos que traigo de la base de datos sin problemas, el detalle es apartir de la segunda linea ya que apartir de ahi es donde no se agregan ese selec, el codigo que tengo para agrgar las lineas esta en JS y es el siguiente

```
$(document).on('click', '#addRows2', function() { 
    count++;
    var htmlRows = '';
    htmlRows += '<tr>';
    htmlRows += '<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="text"   name="productCode2[]" id="productCode2_'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="text"   name="productName2[]" id="productName2_'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>';    
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity2[]"    id="quantity2_'+count+'"    class="form-control quantity2 input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="price2[]"       id="price2_'+count+'"       class="form-control price2 input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>';      
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="total2[]"       id="total2_'+count+'"       class="form-control total2 input-sm" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" name="proveedor2[]"     id="proveedor2_1"           class="form-control price2 input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>';     
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="factura2[]"     id="factura2_1"             class="form-control factura2 input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    htmlRows += '</tr>';
    $('#invoiceItem2').append(htmlRows);
});
```

Entonces la pregunta aqui seria como agregar ese codigo de PHP que trae los proveedores al js que agrega cada linea?, o sea en otras palabras agregarlo aqui

```
htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" name="proveedor2[]"     id="proveedor2_1"           class="form-control price2 input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>';
```

Muchas gracais por su ayuda

**ACTUALIZACION**

Ya lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera,

```
function cargar_provincias()
    {   
        var fruits = [];
        <?php       
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "apporta");
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM app_proveedores Where user_code = 150 order by nombre';
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $nombre=$row['nombre'];
                     ?>
                    fruits.push("<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>"); <?php
                }
            ?>
          fruits.push("MELON");

        for(var i in fruits)
        { 
            document.getElementById("provincia").innerHTML += "<option value='"+fruits[i]+"'>"+fruits[i]+"</option>"; 

        }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que la prueba la hice en un archivo PHP y claro está funcionó sin problemas, pero el archivo que maneja el sistema es un JS entonces el codigo de php no se va a ejecutar, que se podria hacer ahi ? Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

**Vieja escuela**
Ya que estas utilizando PHP de la forma antigua enviando los datos directamente a la vista puede intentar crear un Array de Javascript desde el PHP y recorrelo en la vista cuanto tu deses

```
# Inicio el StringVariable
$objeto_js = '[';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($objeto_js != '[') {
        $objeto_js = $objeto_js . ','
    }
    # Agrego los Valores Como Objetos al StringVariable
    $objeto_js = '{name: "' . $row['nombre'] . '"}';
}

$objeto_js = $objeto_js . ']'; 
# Imprimo el StringVariable ya escrita para el JS
echo 'var arrayDeElementos = ' . $objeto_js . ';';
```

**Consejo**

Para que no tengas problemas en un futuro te aconsejo que investigues como hacer ApiRest con php

> ApiRest es una de las metodologías actuales para pedir datos. De esta manera pagina como facebook obtienen datos sin recargarse

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, a ver si entendi bien, ese codigo que me pasaste lo que hace es crear un array con el resultado del select de la base de datos de PHP? entonces al final tendre un array en la variable $objeto_js ?es asi? entonces luego tendre que crear el combobox del formulario con ese array ? GRacias por la ayuda